# I am trying to display an image through bitmap by fetching it from phpMyAdmin. But the image is not getting displayed

Tags: php, android, mysqli, bitmap

I am trying to display an image through bitmap by fetching it from MySQL but the image is not getting displayed. I've tried a lot but couldn't get this thing.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "select * from output_images where imageId='$id'";
        $r = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
        header('content-type: image/jpeg');
        echo base64_decode($result['imageData']);
        mysqli_close($mysqli);  
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

Here is my Android code that fetches `imageData` from table and displays it through Bitmap.

```
public class TestMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText enterId;
    Button fetchImage;
    ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_main);
        enterId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        fetchImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        fetchImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void getImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>
        {
            protected void onPreExecute(){              
            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...params){
                String id = params[0];
                String url1 = "http://12.0.0.1/demo_d/getImage.php?imageId="+id;
                Bitmap image = null;
                try{
                    URL url = new URL(url1);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return image;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
                super.onPostExecute(image);
                img.setImageBitmap(image);
            }   
}
    String id1 = enterId.getText().toString();
    GetImage i =new GetImage();
    i.execute(id1);
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getImage();
    }
}
```

After the execution of the code I found no errors but there the `ImageView` is blank and the required image is not been displayed.

Comment: you don't fetch "from phpmyadmin". phpmyadmin is a management interface for the mysql database. it is NOT a database itself. plus, is `12.0.0.1` a typo? I highly doubt you're working at the "root" ip of an old-school Class A ip block. `127.0.0.1` maybe?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for that. I'am basically trying to download the image from server.

Comment: Are you running this code on an emulator and is your DB on your machine?

Comment: yes. Its running on emulator and DB is on my machine. @Rohit5k2

Comment: @PoojaYeli: Well in that case see my answer below.

Comment: Sir there is only 1 entry in the DB with id=1. In this case I'm uploading the image to my server with php and have tried using Android downloading with php, So will there be any problem while downloading the image? @Rohit5k2

Comment: @PoojaYeli: If the url is correct and `php` code is working you should have been able to see the image on machine browser using `127.0.0.1`. You can't see it on machine browser also which means something is wrong on server side.

Comment: Sir in this example, I'm uploading the image to my server with php and have tried using Android downloading with php, So will there be any problem while downloading the image? @Rohit5k2

Comment: @PoojaYeli: Shouldn't be any.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use your machine while running this code on Android emulator because you are using IP `127.0.0.1`.

If you use `127.0.0.1` on the emulator it basically points to itself.

To access the host machine from emulator you should use `http://10.0.2.2:8080`.

So, your URL should look like this

```
String url1 = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/demo_d/getImage.php?imageId="+id;
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) for more information on this matter.

Comment: Yes. I've checked with that IP too. Yet the image is not getting displayed.

Comment: @PoojaYeli: Are you able to see the image on machine browser? Try to make a static call using your browser. See if browser displays anything. Url like `http://127.0.0.1/demo_d/getImage.php?imageId=1`

Comment: Yea sir the problem goes there. The image is not being displayed when I do that.

Comment: That means problem is on `php` side or maybe the `id` you are using is not there in the DB.